# Error en javascript: ¿qué significa Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo ese error al poner este código javascript

```
include_once '../connections/conexion.php';

if(isset($_POST['mail_password'])) {
$userId     = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $_POST['user_id']);
$password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $_POST['password_email']);
$cpassword  = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $_POST['cpassword_email']);

$consultaPass = "UPDATE dat_cliente SET pass = '".md5($password)."' WHERE idCliente = '$userId' ";
$result6 = mysqli_query($ConexionBD, $consultaPass);

echo '
    <label class="text-success">Tu contraseña se ha modificado!!</label>
    ';
print "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
         setTimeout('self.close();',7000)
    </script>
    ";
```

}

Comment: Hay una [pregunta en StackOverlow identica a la tuya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome), la cual te sacara toda duda de este tema. Ahora bien, creo que tu problema esta más bien en la usabilidad de tu aplicación. ¿Porque, en el mundo, querrias cerrar la ventana/pestaña despues de actualizar la contraseña? ¿No seria mejor redirigir a la pagina de inicio o login? De igual forma, te recomiendo mucho mantener todo el Javascript del lado del cliente y todo el PHP del lado del servidor. Mezclar todo solo te creara confusion.

Comment: como haces el update eres  candidato a un Sql Inyection

Comment: @KennyBarrera tienez mucha razón, lo haré de la manera en lo que dices, redirigirlo al login, gracias.

Comment: De nada, que bueno que te ayude. La verdad es que las preguntas sin contestar no afectan en nada al sitio, asi que puedes dejarla asi o borrarla, como quieras. Saludos!